# AWS Lambda Modulization Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have recently started Lambda function development on AWS. When try to import a JavaScript file I am getting the following error,and I have also used DynamoDb

```
module initialization error: TypeError
at Object.<anonymous> (/var/task/index.js:14:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

This is my code which I have zipped along with node modules and package.json

```
const alexaSDK = require('alexa-sdk');
const awsSDK = require('aws-sdk');
const promisify = require('es6-promisify');

awsSDK.config.update({
    region: "us-west"
});

//const appId = 'REPLACE WITH YOUR SKILL APPLICATION ID';

const recipesTable = 'Recipes';
const docClient = new awsSDK.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

// convert callback style functions to promises
const dbScan = promisify(docClient.scan, docClient);
const dbGet =  promisify(docClient.get, docClient);
const dbPut = promisify(docClient.put, docClient);
const dbDelete = promisify(docClient.delete, docClient);
```

I have installed everything that is needed.Could anyone help with this error.